# Restful WCF adding message header to outgoing response

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, header

I have been trying to add a custom header with value to outgoing response messages. The value will be different for each user request.

However I could not add the header with value using the following code:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service : IMyService
{
    public string CommandHandler()
    {
        string s = "test";
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("testheader", "123456");
        return s;
    }
}
```

If I add the following code to `global.asax`, it works but `testheader` is always `123`, I can not change the value.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("testheader", "123");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always 123 because you are explicitly setting it to that with:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("testheader", "123");
```

Here's a link for an example of how to create an endpoint behavior and register it correctly. [WCF blog from MS MVP](http://blogs.msmvps.com/paulomorgado/2007/04/26/wcf-building-an-http-user-agent-message-inspector/)